# Update reserved words (with exceptions) using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string

Using this regex in Java 8, I want to update my reserved words with uppercase taking into account these restrictions:

- Capitalize only the reserved words that are between spaces or beginning/end of sentence
- If it is in parentheses or brackets, update it also if it is not included in a word
- Do not update reserved words included within a word or after a hyphen

My code:

```
String[] RESERVED_WORDS = { "id", "url" };
String[] result = {"id report with report-id is in the url but not in the identifier (id)"};
Arrays.stream(RESERVED_WORDS).forEach(word -> result[0] = result[0].replaceAll("(\\b" + word + "\\b", word.toUpperCase()));
```

My result:

```
ID report with report-ID is in the URL but not in the identifier (id)
```

My expectation:

```
ID report with report-id is in the URL but not in the identifier (ID)
```

I have all exceptions handled except the one after the hyphen, any idea yo improve my code?

Comment: Documentation for the method in question says: “ Note that backslashes (\\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.” You may want to start there.

Comment: Whitespace boundaries are `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)`. You need `"(?<!\\S)" + word + "(?!\\S)"` or `"(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?!\\S)"`

Comment: FYI: https://ideone.com/8HgTsS

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But for the example: "Base rate usd (usd)" doesnt work, the second usd doesnt change and need to change too, any idea to fix?

Comment: Please see what requirements you have: *Capitalize only the reserved words that are between spaces or beginning/end of sentence*. According to *your* requirements, `(usd)` should not match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I know, I updated the exceptions, what is your idea now? Can you help me?

Comment: `(?<![-\w])id(?![-\w])`, see https://regex101.com/r/u7ot3L/1 and https://ideone.com/Ak7r9H (`"(?<![\\w-])" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?![\\w-])"`)

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew one more question, how can I do so that in this regular expression, for Pattern.quote(word) it does not take into account upper or lower case when comparing it with the reserved words? Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the regex search case insensitive? Add `(?i)`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/Tr0e8V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
String[] RESERVED_WORDS = { "id", "url" };
String[] result = {"id report with report-id is in the url but not in the identifier (id)"};
Arrays.stream(RESERVED_WORDS).forEach(word -> result[0] = result[0].replaceAll("(?i)(?<![\\w-])" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?![\\w-])", word.toUpperCase()));
System.out.println(result[0]);
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Tr0e8V), output:

```
ID report with report-id is in the URL but not in the identifier (ID)
```

The `"(?i)(?<![\\w-])" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?![\\w-])"` part creates a [regex like](https://regex101.com/r/u7ot3L/2) `(?i)(?<![-\w])id(?![-\w])` that matches `id` in a case insensitive way (due to the `(?i)` embedded flag option) that is not preceded with a `-` or any word char, and is not followed by `-` or any word char.